# SharePoint - VirtualPathProvider: Register within FeatureReceiver

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, virtualpathprovider

I'm trying to implement an VirtualPathProvider for SharePoint 2010/2013 (Server and Foundation). So far I've implemented subclasses of `System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider`, `System.Web.Hosting.VirtualFile` and `System.Web.Hosting.VirtualDirectory`.

I wanted to use a feature with `FeatureReceiver` class to register the new VPP with the HostingEnvironment. But since I have implemented the line

`HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVPProvider());`

into the `FeatureActivated` method, VisualStudio's debug deployment fails with:

`Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Maybe a `FeatureReceiver` is the wrong place to register the VPP?

I've already searched the web for an tutorial or example but I didn't find any suitable. Any hint on how to develop a VirtualPathProvider for SharePoint is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

--

Robert Vogel

Comment: Hi RObert, Have you solved this problem? I am trying to run RazarViewEngine from a datalayer but getting files from Database instead of File locations. I get this error. I am pretty sure because there is no hosting environment but there must be a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an IHttpModule implementation which registers your virtual path provider **ones**.
Maybe this link helps you: [SharePoint 2007 as a WCF host - Step #4, Write a Virtual Path Provider](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-5-SharePoint_2007_as_a_WCF_host_-_Step_-4,_Write_a_Virtual_Path_Provider.aspx)

```
using System.Web;
public class MyVirtualPathProviderRegisterModule : IHttpModule
{
    static bool _Initialized = false;
    static object _Lock = new object();
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        if (!_Initialized)
            lock(_Lock)
                if(!_Initialized)
                {
                    HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVirtualPathProvider());
                    _Initialized = true;
                }
    }
    public void Dispose() {}
}
```